# Items not being displayed in cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, cart

I'm encountering an issue with my React Redux Cart component where although items are being added to the cart state via the addItem action, they aren't rendering on the Cart page.

Problem:

When I add items to the cart using the addItem action, I can see the state updating in Redux DevTools or through logging the state within the component.
However, the Cart component doesn't display the added items despite the state reflecting their presence.
What I've Checked:

Confirmed that the addItem action in the cartSlice reducer properly updates the state by logging the entire cart state after adding items.
Verified the rendering logic in the Cart component for mapping through the cart state and displaying items.

cart:

```
export default function Cart() {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  console.log("Cart component rendered");

  console.log(cart);

  return (
    <div
      className="cart-container"
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Background})` }}
    >
      <h1>Your Cart</h1>
      {cart.length === 0 ? (
        <p>No items in your cart</p>
      ) : (
        cart.map((item) => (
          <div className="cart-item" key={item.id}>
            <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
            <div className="cart-item-details">
              <h3>{item.name}</h3>
              <p>Price: {item.price}DT</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

cartSlice:

```
export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    cart: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      const { id, name, price, image, size, quantity } = action.payload;
      const calculatedPrice = price[size] * quantity;

      const newItem = {
        id,
        name,
        price: calculatedPrice,
        image,
        size,
        quantity,
      };

      state.cart = [...state.cart, newItem];
    },
    removeItem: (state, action) => {
      state.cart = state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    cleanCart: (state) => {
      state.cart = [];
    },
  },
});
```

menu:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCalculatedPrice(prices[selectedSize] * quantity);
  }, [selectedSize, quantity, prices]);

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    if (quantity > 0) {
      const selectedItem = {
        id,
        name,
        price: prices[selectedSize], // This assumes `prices` is an object with different price values
        image,
        size: selectedSize,
        quantity,
      };
      dispatch(addItem(selectedItem));
      navigate("/cart");
    } else {
      console.log("Choose more!");
    }
  };
```

store:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

import userReducer from "./user/userSlice.js";
import cartReducer from "./cart/cartSlice.js";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
  })
);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: The only issue I see is that the `payload.prices` property is already a scaler value instead of an object when dispatching the `addItem(selectedItem)` action in the menu. I don't think this would cause the UI to not rerender with the updated selected cart state. Can you [edit] to share how you have created the store so it's clear what you selecting from state? See [mcve].

Comment: question updated, i will do my best with my next question @DrewReese I got a different error now since i've made a couple of changes, one with price and prices variables naming and second to ensure i'm updating updating the state immutably within reducer,

Comment: the cart component is being rendered, i get undefined and in state i se them added, error in console is cart.map is not a function @DrewReese

Comment: they showed! i changed this one mine const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart); to this => const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart?.cart); @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are not selecting deep enough into state to get the actual cart array.

```js
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
  })
);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
```

```js
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
```

`state.cart` is ***only*** the cart slice, e.g. `{ cart: [....] }` that is the cart slice's state.

Additionally, the cart reducer incorrectly assumes that `action.payload.price` is the object of price values by size and attemptes to recompute a price value when computing a total cost.

```js
const selectedItem = {
  id,
  name,
  price: prices[selectedSize], // <-- is already a price value
  image,
  size: selectedSize,
  quantity,
};
dispatch(addItem(selectedItem));
```

```js
addItem: (state, action) => {
  const { id, name, price, image, size, quantity } = action.payload;
  const calculatedPrice = price[size] * quantity; // <-- price[size] is undefined

  const newItem = {
    id,
    name,
    price: calculatedPrice,
    image,
    size,
    quantity,
  };

  state.cart = [...state.cart, newItem];
},
```

The result of `price[size] * quantity`, or `undefined * quantity`, is `NaN`

## Solution

To access the cart array access one level deeper into the selected cart state.

```js
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cart);
```

Or destructure `cart` from the selected cart state

```js
const { cart } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
```

To address the total cost issue you simply need to use `price * quantity`, assuming that `price` is number-like type, e.g. a number type or number-like String value.

```js
addItem: (state, action) => {
  const { id, name, price, image, size, quantity } = action.payload;
  const calculatedPrice = price * quantity;

  const newItem = {
    id,
    name,
    price: calculatedPrice,
    image,
    size,
    quantity,
  };

  state.cart = [...state.cart, newItem];
},
```

Or this can be computed in the UI prior to being dispatched.

```js
const selectedItem = {
  id,
  name,
  price: prices[selectedSize] * quantity,
  image,
  size: selectedSize,
  quantity,
};
dispatch(addItem(selectedItem));
```

```js
addItem: (state, action) => {
  state.cart.push(action.payload);
},
```